SSDT DLLs for VS 2019
I have installed VS 2019 on Windows Server 2019 with the SSDT 2019 extension installed. I need the v4.0_15x DLL in the GAC for Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS but its giving me v4.0_11x, v4.0_12x, v4.0_13x. When I have installed SQL Server 19 on other servers and add SSIS that way it gives me the v4.0_15x DLL. Should the SSDT 2019 extension be providing the DLL for v4.0_15x? Is what it is currently giving me the expected result? Where would I find a list of DLLs that are installed with SSDT 2019?
Im looking to do this without manually installing DLLs into the GAC and I am hoping there is an SSDT install I can use to get this DLL.
I did the same install on my PC and got the same libraries. I tried upgrading the extension in VS but it didnt add the dll I need.

Is this what you are looking for:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-ver16
